# how do I permanently set a system variable ([System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable) in windows 11?

Tags: powershell

As above.

I tried (inside powershell terminal with run as admin)

```
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('ResourceGroup','AZ_Resource_Group')
```

and the variable is only available for that window. If I open another powershell window or restart my PC, the variable is lost.

Thanks

Comment: Why don’t you create the system variable through the GUI?

Comment: What a funny question to ask about PowerShell in a site for Super Users.

Comment: @KevinBuchan what make it fun?

Comment: @Ooker I think Kevin meant that Ramhound's question about using the GUI was funny, since this site includes a lot of people who need answers that can be run as part of a script.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Please specify the `scope` when setting the variable:

[Saving environment variables with SetEnvironmentVariable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-7.2#saving-environment-variables-with-setenvironmentvariable)

> On Windows, you can specify a scope for the SetEnvironmentVariable method as the third parameter to set the environment variable in that scope. **The machine and user scopes both persist outside of the current process,** allowing you to save a new or changed environment variable.

```
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('ResourceGroup','AZ_Resource_Group', 'Machine')
```

```
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('ResourceGroup','AZ_Resource_Group', 'User')
```

Comment: Anyone else is getting this error? (Run PowerShell as administrator will fix it) `Exception calling "SetEnvironmentVariable" with "3" argument(s): "Requested registry access is not allowed."`

Comment: @HafizTemuri Good call. **In order for this to work, you need to be running PowerShell as an administrator.** (In my case it "worked" but silently failed, i.e. I reopen PS and the environment variable is unset.) Good grief...